# Create an "intranet-in-a-box" that hosts Node.JS web application and is accessible from wifi

Tags: networking, server, nodejs, wireless-access-point, intranet

I have an OrangePi5 running Ubuntu Server 22.04.

Basically what I'd like is to have it host a node.js webserver application on the orangepi.

I want to make a wireless network on this same OrangePi and have the node.js Web app running on that network.

I then need to broadcast that network using the OrangePi as an access point.

I want my users to be able to see the SSID, connect to the AP and then be able to access the Node.JS Web app via their browser on their device.

I don't want the AP to bridge an Internet connection. The network on the Pi should be self contained like a little intranet.

The problem I keep running into is that I turn the OrangePi into an access point, I have a Node server running on that same Pi, but connecting to the AP and then entering the IP address of the Node app doesn't connect to anything. I think I'm missing how to have this AP and web app be on the same the same network.